# YouTube Analytics API PHP: usageLimits accessNotConfigured

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics

I am using the [Google Analytics API PHP] by wanze. I was able to set up authentication (using web auth only) and everything and I stored the token in a session. On another page, I use this code to find all the accounts the user logged in with.

```
session_start();
include('GoogleAnalyticsAPI.class.php');

$ga = new GoogleAnalyticsAPI(); 
$ga->auth->setClientId('replaces'); // From the APIs console
$ga->auth->setClientSecret('replaces'); // From the APIs console
$ga->auth->setRedirectUri('replaced'); // Url to your app, must match one in the APIs console

// Get the Auth-Url
$url = $ga->auth->buildAuthUrl();

// Set the accessToken and Account-Id
$ga->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
$ga->setAccountId('ga:xxxxxxx');

// Load profiles
$profiles = $ga->getProfiles();
print_r($profiles);
$accounts = array();
foreach ($profiles['items'] as $item) {
    $id = "ga:{$item['id']}";
    $name = $item['name'];
    $accounts[$id] = $name;
}
// Print out the Accounts with Id => Name. Save the Id (array-key) of the account you want to query data. 
// See next chapter how to set the account-id.
print_r($accounts);
```

I this returned:

```
Array
(
    [http_code] => 403
    [error] => Array
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [domain] => usageLimits
                            [reason] => accessNotConfigured
                            [message] => Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.
                            [extendedHelp] => https://console.developers.google.com
                        )

                )

            [code] => 403
            [message] => Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.
        )

)
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home3/chalzzy/public_html/dashboard/dashboard.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
Array
(
)
```

I see in a lot of places that I need to remove or set all refers in a "Referrals" section in the console but I can't seem to fins that in the new or old console. If it is there and I can't find it, can you please give me a url or a screenshot?

Also, these are all the APIs I have installed for this project:

[image: List of API]

Thanks in advance,

Ben

**Also, let me know if you need more details!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey (I'm sorry it was a very stupid question),

What you have to do is add to your APIs list "Analytics API" in the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).